# Why does Python imaplib return Errno 111: Connection refused when I try to instantiate the IMAP4() object in GitPod?

Tags: sockets, imaplib, gitpod

I am trying to use the Python imaplib library in GitPod.

Following the documentation, I imported imaplib and instantiated the IMAP4 object with the following line of code:

`M = imaplib.IMAP4()`

This returns the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 198, in __init__
    self.open(host, port)
  File "/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 303, in open
    self.sock = self._create_socket()
  File "/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 293, in _create_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, self.port))
  File "/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Is the problem that the imaplib is not able to connect to its own socket, and so I should somehow activate that socket inside GitPod first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4):

> *class imaplib.IMAP4(host='', port=IMAP4_PORT, timeout=None)*
> This class implements the actual IMAP4 protocol. The connection is created and protocol version (IMAP4 or IMAP4rev1) is determined when the instance is initialized. **If host is not specified, '' (the local host) is used.**

Thus, it tries to connect to the IMAP server on the local machine. Looks like there is none or at least not at port 143.

Comment: Thank you. So the issue is that the GitPod Docker container doesn't have an IMAP server? I thought that I would access my emails from a remote IMAP server (gmail), and that I wouldn't need an IMAP server on my end. Does that mean that this library does not provide the functionality I had in mind (retrieving email)? Or should I just create an IMAP server on my end to communicate with the remote one? Thank you very much

Comment: @PeterElbert: The library is for retrieving email. You need some server to retrieve email from. This server need to be given as argument, i.e. something like imap.gmail.com. I have no idea why you think that GitPod would include a mail server and where the mail on this server should come from.

Comment: Got it, so I pass the server address in the instantiation. The documentation example shows this class being instantiated with no argument so I was following their example. I thought I would pass that information afterwards. I didn't think GitPod contained a mail server.